# Parallel mapping x.f() instead of f(x) for many functions

Tags: python, pandas, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I have a very large pandas data frame, over which I want to map many functions.
Because the frame is large, I wrote some code to parallelize this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import cpu_count(), Pool

my_frame = pd.DataFrame(...) # A large data frame with the column "data"

def parallel_map(series: pd.Series, func):
    cores = cpu_count()
    partitions = cores
    data_split = np.array_split(series, partitions)
    print(f"Parallelizing with {cores} cores...")
    with Pool(cores) as pool:
        data = pd.concat(pool.map(func, data_split))
    pool.join()
    return data
```

What I want to call this with is `pd.Series.map`, i.e. I want to compute things for each row; something like this:

```
def transform_data(entry):
    # Do expensive stuff
    return entry
```

Non-parallel, I could now do

```
my_frame["data"].map(transform_data)
```

However, for the parallel version, I need to define an additional function in the global namespace to invert the caller, because `Pool.map` applies `f(x)`, but I want to call `x.f()`. The function needs to be pickle-able to be able to be run by the Pool:

```
def inverted_transform_data(column: pd.Series):
    return column.map(transform_data)
```

Now I can call the parallel version like this:

```
parallel_map(data=my_frame["data"], func=inverted_transform_data)
```

The problem is that I want to do this for many functions that need to be handles sequentially, i.e. `transform_data1, transform_data2, ...`. This requires me to create this global wrapper function for each of them.

Is there a better alternative that is still pickle-able?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up a "low budget" solution, because I did not want to introduce dask as a dependency. It just creates a callable wrapper class:

```
class InvertedCallerMap(object):

    def __init__(self, func):
        """
        Required so the parallel map can call x.f() instead of f(x) without running into pickling issues
        :param func: Function to invert from x.f() to f(x)
        """
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, column: pd.Series):
        return column.map(self.func)


def parallel_map(series, func, invert=True):
    cores = cpu_count()
    partitions = cores
    data_split = np.array_split(series, partitions)
    if invert:
        func = InvertedCallerMap(func=func)
    with Pool(cores) as pool:
        data = pd.concat(pool.map(func, data_split))
    pool.join()
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

Dask! https://dask.org/

Dask is a project specifically geared toward parallel pandas. I strongly encourage you to consider it for your use case. If you just want performance gains while sticking with pandas, check out the docs here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html

And this article I found particularly helpful:

https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6

Edit:

With dask you would do:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = # import method such as dd.read_csv("df.csv")
df.apply(func, ...) # or dd.data_col.apply(func, ...)
df.compute()
```